# The joint p.d.f of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ if given p.d.f of $X_1$ and $X_2$

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ denote a random sample of size 2 from a distribution that is normal$( \mu, \sigma^2)$.

Let $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ and $Y_2=X_1-X_2$.
Find joint p.d.f of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and show that these random variables are independent.

Note: My teacher said it can be solved through Change of Variable Technique. But I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets you up for how to change the variables as your teacher suggested:

Rearranging the definitions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, you get $X_1=Y_1-X_2$ and $X_1=Y_2+X_2$. Set those equal, solve for $X_2$, and substitute that in for $X_2$ in the definition of $X_1$, which results in 
$$
X_1 = \frac{Y_1+Y_2}{2} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ X_2= \frac{Y_1-Y_2}{2}
$$
You know the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is bivariate normal with $\rho=0$ because they're random samples. Then
$$
f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = f_{X_1,X_2}(\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},\frac{y_1-y_2}{2})\vert J \vert
$$
where $\vert J \vert$ is the Jacobian of partial derivatives.

Comment: I have another question just like this but in that it was said that show that the joint pdf of Y1=X1+X2 and Y2=X1+2X2 is bivariate normal with correlation coefficient 3/√10

Comment: But X1 and X2 are independent as they are from a random sample so in this case too rho will be zero? Or 3/√10?

Comment: $\rho=0$ when describing the joint of $X_1,X_2$ because they are random samples. Since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are linear combinations of $X_1$ and $X_2$ the $Y$'s don't **have** to be independent.  Once you have the joint pdf of $Y_1, Y_2$, if you can factor it into marginal distributions for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ then you know the $Y$'s are independent - otherwise if you need to show a specific value of $\rho$ you should be able to compare the distribution you calculate to a bivariate normal distribution with the given value of $\rho$

Comment: Will X1 and X2 have parameters mu1 nd sigma1 and mu2 sigma2 respectively? Or just mu nd sigma?

Comment: They're samples from the same distribution, so they have the same parameters....